# Airflow SFTPHook - No hostkey for host found

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to use the Airflow [SFTPHook](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/sftp_hook.py) by passing in a `ssh_conn_id` and I'm getting an error:

```
No hostkey for host myhostname found.
```

Using the [SFTPOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/sftp_hook.py) with the same `ssh_conn_id` however is working fine. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: SFTPHook should take `ftp_conn_id` instead of `ssh_conn_id`.

Answer (score 3):

Just had this issue, the simple trick is to keep your SSH connector inside airflow and to add the following in the "Extra" field :

```
{"no_host_key_check": true}
```

Hope it helps !

Edit : Indeed, it allows the man-in-the-middle attack, so even if it helps temporarily, you should get the ssh fingerprint and allow it

Comment: Disabling the host key check is not recommended as it leaves you vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: @CookieMonster As I understand it is indeed not recommended to do this in production. However, is there an alternative method described anywhere? Running a managed Airflow cluster using Cloud Composer, I do not see where I can modify the `~/.ssh/known_hosts file`.

Answer (score 0):

The `SFTPOperators` uses `SSHHook`. Hence, you should use `SSHHook` instead.

Comment: I experienced the same issue with the SSHHook. It seems that Paramiko was looking for the known_hosts file in this path: /home/airflow/.ssh/known_hosts. In the end I wasn't able to figure out how to get it working since I have no access to the path from Composer and I resorted to writing my own implementation using pysftp.