# Airflow SFTPHook transport.py Authentication (password) failed using Private Key

Tags: authentication, airflow, sftp, private-key

I am running Airflow v2.3.2 / Python 3.10 from the Docker Image below.

```
apache/airflow:2.3.2-python3.10
```

The Docker Image has set `paramiko==2.7.2` in order to address the authentication issues that had been seen in testing.

When calling the sftp, I am using the following:

```
sftp = SFTPHook("connection|sftp")
sftp.look_for_keys = False
sftp.get_conn()
```

I have also tried it without the `sftp.look_for_keys` line.

In the Connections within the Airflow UI, I have configured the `Extra` section as follows:

```
{
    "private_key": "privatekeyinfo", 
    "no_host_key_check": true
}
```

`"privatekeyinfo"` is string format "-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY----- with '\n' line breaks written in.

When I test the connection within the UI, it reports `Connection successfully tested`. However, when the script that calls the Hook runs, I receive the following:

```
[TIMESTAMP] {transport.py:1819} INFO - Connected (version 2.0, client dropbear)
[TIMESTAMP] {transport.py:1819} INFO - Authentication (password) failed.
```

I have also attempted to pass the `"host_key"` in the `Extras` field but get the same Authentication error.

To be explicit, I have tried the following -

1. `sftp.look_for_keys = False` and `"no_host_key_check": true`
2. `sftp.look_for_keys = False` and `"host_key": "host_key_value"`
3. `#sftp.look_for_keys = False` and `"no_host_key_check": true`
4. `#sftp.look_for_keys = False` and `"host_key": "host_key_value"`
5. `Connections` in the Airflow is successful for `"no_host_key_check": true` in `Extras`
6. `Connections` in the Airflow is successful for `"host_key": "host_key_value"` in `Extras`

## Referenced SO questions -

- [Airflow SFTPHook - No hostkey for host found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325376/airflow-sftphook-no-hostkey-for-host-found)
- [Paramiko AuthenticationException issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135261/paramiko-authenticationexception-issue)
- [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939454/verify-host-key-with-pysftp)
- ["Failed to load HostKeys" warning while connecting to SFTP server with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521549/failed-to-load-hostkeys-warning-while-connecting-to-sftp-server-with-pysftp)
- [How to use Airflow to SSH into a server with RSA public/private keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428238/how-to-use-airflow-to-ssh-into-a-server-with-rsa-public-private-keys)
- ["No hostkey for host ***** found" when connecting to SFTP server with pysftp using private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53864260/no-hostkey-for-host-found-when-connecting-to-sftp-server-with-pysftp-usi)

Additional Logging from Paramiko -

```
[TIMESTAMP] {transport.py:1819} DEBUG - starting thread (client mode): 0x9e33d000
[TIMESTAMP] {transport.py:1819} DEBUG - Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.7.2
[TIMESTAMP] {transport.py:1819} DEBUG - Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-dropbear [SERVER]
[TIMESTAMP] {transport.py:1819} INFO - Connected (version 2.0, client dropbear)
[TIMESTAMP] {transport.py:1819} DEBUG - kex algos:['diffie-hellman-group1-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'] server key:['ssh-dss', 'ssh-rsa'] client encrypt:['blowfish-cbc', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc'] server encrypt:['blowfish-cbc', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc'] client mac:['hmac-sha1', 'hmac-md5-96', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5'] server mac:['hmac-sha1', 'hmac-md5-96', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5'] client compress:['none'] server compress:['none'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
[TIMESTAMP] {transport.py:1819} DEBUG - Kex agreed: diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
[TIMESTAMP] {transport.py:1819} DEBUG - HostKey agreed: ssh-rsa
[TIMESTAMP] {transport.py:1819} DEBUG - Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
[TIMESTAMP] {transport.py:1819} DEBUG - MAC agreed: hmac-sha1
[TIMESTAMP] {transport.py:1819} DEBUG - Compression agreed: none
[TIMESTAMP] {transport.py:1819} DEBUG - kex engine KexGroup14SHA256 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
[TIMESTAMP] {transport.py:1819} DEBUG - Switch to new keys ...
[TIMESTAMP] {transport.py:1819} DEBUG - Attempting password auth...
[TIMESTAMP] {transport.py:1819} DEBUG - userauth is OK
[TIMESTAMP] {transport.py:1819} INFO - Authentication (password) failed.
```

Additionally -
The SFTP Server already has the public key and can be connected to using the private key (verified both using CyberDuck as well as a locally running version of Airflow).

Even on the hosted version of Airflow, in the `Connections` section within the `Admin` drop-down, when I go into the sftp connection and select `Test` it returns `Connection successfully tested`. The issue only occurs is within the DAG as it looks like it is trying to authenticate using a password instead of the private key that is provided for that connection.

Link to Airflow GH discussion - https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/31318

Comment: have you also added your public key part of the key pair on remote?

Comment: It indeed does not look like the key was even tried. Btw, what is `privatekeyinfo`? + Note that "hostkey" has nothing to do with your problem. Do not lose your time with those settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of tinkering, ended up finding a solution that doesn't directly use the SFTPHook.

```
def send_to_sftp(filename):
    var_key = Variable.get("Key")
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.client.WarningPolicy)
    host = "host.com"
    key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(io.StringIO(var_key))
    ssh.connect(host, port=###, username='xxxxxxxx', pkey=key, disabled_algorithms=dict(pubkeys=["rsa-sha2-512", "rsa-sha2-256"]))
    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
    sftp.put('./'+filename,filename)
    print('File uploaded')
```

It also appears, after testing locally on a machine that hadn't created the pub/private key pair, that installing a newer sftp and ssh provider did the trick.

The root of the problem came from the authentication not looking to the private key that was passed in the `Extras` field and then failing when it could not find a password.